# run whamlet in pure code?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

In a yesod application, I want to create URL attributes for a graph that will be rendered by [graphviz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz) , and I want to use interpolation. Ideally,

```
graphToDot nonClusteredParams { fmtNode = \ (n,l) -> 
     [ URL [whamlet| @{MyRoute ...} |]
   } g
```

Of course, the types don't match:

- attribute of `URL` is pure `Text`, but `whamlet` is monadic (widget)
- when I replace by `shamlet`, type is fine, but it cannot interpolate: `URL interpolation used, but no URL renderer provided`

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This works: get the render function (in the monad), and apply (in pure code)

```
render <- getUrlRender 
let d = graphToDot ... 
     [ URL $ render $ MyRoute ... ]
```

I found this here, where a similar problem is solved: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Using-type-safe-urls-from-inside-javascript